# Making ScrollViewer's ScrollBar always visible through overriding or styling

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to make the ScrollBar for the ScrollViewer to be always visible so it doesn't only appear when I try to scroll the text view and so the user knows that there is someting more to see.
At first, for some reason, I thought that I just have to change the color which needed brush overriding, but in reality, the ScrollBar is fading in and fading out, so either the ScrollViewer's or ScrollBar's template needs to be changed.

I found the ScrollViewer's template which I have just placed in the App.Resources section, but I don't know how to edit it so the ScrollBar is just visible all the time:

```
<Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Enabled" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalScrollMode" Value="Enabled" />
    <Setter Property="IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="ZoomMode" Value="Enabled" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ScrollingIndicatorStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition From="MouseIndicator" To="NoIndicator">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ScrollBarSeparator" BeginTime="0:0:3" />
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalScrollBar"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <ScrollingIndicatorMode>None</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalScrollBar"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <ScrollingIndicatorMode>None</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition From="TouchIndicator" To="NoIndicator">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ScrollBarSeparator" />
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalScrollBar"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <ScrollingIndicatorMode>None</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalScrollBar"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <ScrollingIndicatorMode>None</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>

                            <VisualState x:Name="NoIndicator">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ScrollBarSeparator" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="TouchIndicator">
                                <Storyboard>
                                                                            <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="ScrollBarSeparator" />

                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalScrollBar"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode"
                                                               Duration="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <ScrollingIndicatorMode>TouchIndicator</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalScrollBar"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode"
                                                               Duration="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <ScrollingIndicatorMode>TouchIndicator</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseIndicator">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="ScrollBarSeparator" />
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalScrollBar"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode"
                                                               Duration="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <ScrollingIndicatorMode>MouseIndicator</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalScrollBar"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode"
                                                               Duration="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <ScrollingIndicatorMode>MouseIndicator</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="ScrollContentPresenter"
                                            Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                        <ScrollBar x:Name="VerticalScrollBar"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               IsTabStop="False"
                               Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                               Orientation="Vertical"
                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                               Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                               ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                        <ScrollBar x:Name="HorizontalScrollBar"
                               IsTabStop="False"
                               Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                               Orientation="Horizontal"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                               Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                               ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" />
                        <!-- Change the opacity below, to zero. otherwise, the right and bottom border end up showing up as a single pixel lit on the screen even if the scroll is disabled. -->
                        <Border x:Name="ScrollBarSeparator"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Opacity="0"
                            BorderThickness="0,0,1,1"
                            Background="{StaticResource ScrollBarTrackBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource ScrollBarTrackBorderThemeBrush}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I tried deleting various parts of the code, but, in result, the ScrollBar just disappears altogether.

[image: I want the ScrollBar to appear all the time without fading out like this.]

Comment: Please add snapshot for your question.

Comment: As requested, I added an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To achieve expected result you need to change style of **Scrollbar** as scrollviewer is made of scrollbar.

**Working scrollbar**

```
 <x:Double x:Key="ScrollBarMinThemeWidth">7</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="ScrollBarMinThemeHeight">7</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="ScrollBarPanningThumbThemeHeight">2.4</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="ScrollBarPanningThumbThemeWidth">2.4</x:Double>
    <Style  TargetType="ScrollBar">
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarMinThemeWidth}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarMinThemeHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollBar">
                    <Grid x:Name="Root" Background="Red">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Root"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ScrollingIndicatorStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="TouchIndicator">
                                    <!--<Storyboard>
                                        <FadeInThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalPanningRoot"/>
                                        <FadeInThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalPanningRoot"/>
                                    </Storyboard>-->
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseIndicator"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="NoIndicator">
                                    <!--<Storyboard>
                                        <FadeOutThemeAnimation BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalPanningRoot"/>
                                        <FadeOutThemeAnimation BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalPanningRoot"/>
                                    </Storyboard>-->
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid x:Name="HorizontalPanningRoot" MinWidth="53">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalPanningThumb" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Fill="{ThemeResource ScrollBarPanningBackgroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="{ThemeResource ScrollBarPanningThumbThemeHeight}" MinWidth="{ThemeResource ScrollBarMinThemeWidth}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid x:Name="VerticalPanningRoot" MinHeight="53">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalPanningThumb" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Fill="{ThemeResource ScrollBarPanningBackgroundThemeBrush}" MinHeight="{ThemeResource ScrollBarMinThemeHeight}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{ThemeResource ScrollBarPanningThumbThemeWidth}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

<ScrollViewer Height="300" Margin="30" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <TextBlock FontSize="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum."/>      
</ScrollViewer>
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: I tried, only one issue, you cannot click on scrollbar to do scrolling.  it does not respond. any solution ?

Comment: @Neha this answer provides the link to the source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75031628/6368401

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just set the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` and/or the `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` of your instance of the `ScrollViewer` to `Visible`, as opposed to removing the fading behaviour from the style?

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
     <!-- ScrollViewer Content -->
</ScrollViewer>
```

EDIT AFTER COMMENT:

I think I came up with a "solution". I'm not sure if it's the best way achieving this, but it seems to give the result you want.

Create a custom style for the`ScrollViewer`, then make one for the vertical/horizontal `ScrollBar` itself (using Blend, which is what I assumed you did before).
Once you have a copy of the default style, edit the following lines:

```
<VisualState x:Name="NoIndicator">
    <Storyboard>
        <FadeOutThemeAnimation BeginTime="0" TargetName="HorizontalPanningRoot"/>
        <FadeOutThemeAnimation BeginTime="0" TargetName="VerticalPanningRoot"/>
        <Fade**In**ThemeAnimation BeginTime="0" TargetName="HorizontalRoot"/>
        <Fade**In**ThemeAnimation BeginTime="0" TargetName="VerticalRoot"/>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

My guess is that this literally causes the `ScrollBar` to fade in when it is not being interacted with, meaning it will always be visible.

Here's the relevant ScrollViewer XAML (I can't fit the whole thing in the answer). Notice that the ScrollViewer is set to use my custom style `ScrollViewerStyle1`, then within that style the `VerticalScrollBar` is set to my `ScrollBar` custom style `ScrollBarCustomStyle1`, where the `NoIndicator VisualState` is modified. You can do the same to the horizontal scroll bar if you need to.

ScrollViewer Style:

```
<ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="ScrollContentPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
<ScrollBar x:Name="VerticalScrollBar" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsTabStop="False" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarStyle1}"/>
<ScrollBar x:Name="HorizontalScrollBar" IsTabStop="False" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
<Border x:Name="ScrollBarSeparator" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ScrollBarTrackBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" Background="{ThemeResource ScrollBarTrackBackgroundThemeBrush}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to mention I tried / googled it already. It doesn't work like that: "There is a bit of a leaky abstraction here where Visible doesn't quite mean the same thing to the ScrollViewer as it does to a human reader. With VerticalScrollBarVisibility set to Visible the ScrollBar is always there and "Visible" as far as the ScrollViewer is concerned. Within the ScrollBar itself though, the scrollbar and thumb only draw if it is in MouseIndicator mode: the default ScrollBar styles don't display if the user isn't interacting with them by mouse." http://tinyurl.com/och8xrz

Comment: Edited answer, see above

Comment: By using the default style from here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj710190.aspx), I'm getting 4 ThemeBrush and ThemeThickness errors (the resource could not be resolved). Could you please provide the default style you're using? Previously I tried resolving the fading in and out through Blend ScrollViewer's states, but appearently I don't have something installed.

Comment: Updated. I also changed my original instructions a little, so check those again as well.

Comment: I think some part of the answer is missing or you forgot the link. :)

Comment: I just commented out the VisualState NoIndicator lines and now it appears to work.