# .NET MAUI : Override the default style of a windows view (TextBox)

Tags: xaml, xamarin, .net-maui, winui

I want to create a custom **Entry** with a completely personalized visual.

For this, I created a **CustomEntryHandler** to modify the native view of the windows platform but I can't override the basic windows style which imports some effects :

- The background color that changes on over
- The bottom border that is displayed when entry is focused
- ...

I think I understood that this style comes from the default style of windows, in the generic.xaml file.
Does anyone know how I can override this ?

```
        protected  override TextBox CreatePlatformView()
    {
        var nativeView = new TextBox();

        nativeView.Margin = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
        nativeView.FocusVisualMargin = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
        nativeView.BorderThickness = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Thickness(0,0,0,0);
        nativeView.Padding = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
        nativeView.CornerRadius = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.CornerRadius(0);
        nativeView.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);

        return nativeView;
    }
```

[Screenshot of the entry focused with code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FetK.png)

---

**UPDATE 11/10/22** : I also want to remove the **Clear** button of the TextBox.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "visual effect on the mouse over" of a TextBox ?

Comment: Hello @Cfun, I edited my post, I hope that answers your question. Thanks

Comment: Is it OK to code in XAML?

Comment: Yes, I tried without success.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to write a new Style and apply it to your control using this code:

```
var nativeView = new TextBox();
nativeView.Style = Application.Current.Resources["MyCustomTextBoxStyle"];
```

In your App.xaml, you need to add the following style:

```
<Style x:Key="MyCustomTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
<!-- Your textbox style -->
</Style>
```

You can find the standard WinUI 2 TextBox style [here](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/dev/CommonStyles/TextBox_themeresources.xaml). If you would like to remove the clear button, you could remove the button that is part of the TextBoxStyle [here](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/dev/CommonStyles/TextBox_themeresources.xaml#L455-L467).